# rails helper to create a valid URI (with escape characters)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url

is there any existing rails helper to create a valid URL?

Specifically, I am generating a Web URL with some parameters that having special character (for e.g space i need to convert into + , and many others special characters).

http://domain.name?param1=ABC+DEF&param2=GHI

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `CGI.escape` to do that.

```
CGI.escape("foo bar") # 'foo+bar'
```